# Supplying an action to the tagName on a component

Tags: ember.js

I am creating a component based on [this](http://jsbin.com/fotuqa/edit?html,css,js,output) jsbin.

The trouble is that it is wrapped inside of a div.  This wrecks some formatting I have.  I changed it to use `tagName : 'select'` and removed the `<select>` tag from the template, however, how do I use the `{{action 'change' on='change'}}` that was previously in the template and apply it to the tagName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an onchange handler in your component.js by providing a `change` method.

```
// components/my-select/component.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    ...
    change() { 
        this.sendAction('change', ...);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this change() method only executed in the context of the root tag?  what if there was a template that had a few other tags that could potentially produce change events also?

Comment: It will be fired when the change event arrives at the top level element, whether it originates there or somewhere down below. In this case, however, I think only the `select` element itself would be emitting a `change` event.